# React: get data after form submit using async/await

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I'm fetching data from API and I have a problem with displaying them to the screen. I want to get data when user type something in form and click button submit.
I have an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'main' of null

I do not understand why this data not display on the screen. If none were displayed it would have more sense to me. But if I comment this line, props.data.city from ChildComponent displaying correctly. My code:

```
class ExampleComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    city: null
  }

  getData = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const city = e.target.elements.city.value;
    const getData = await fetch(`${url}${city}&appid=${key}`);
    const data = await getData.json();

    this.setState({
      city: data
    });
    console.log(this.state.city); // return correct value, not null
    console.log(this.state.city.main.temp_min); // return correct value, not null
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <FormComponent onSubmit={this.getData} />
        <ChildComponent data={this.state.city} />
      </>
    );
  }
}

const FormComponent = props => (
  <form onSubmit={props.getData}>
    <input type="text" name="city" />
    <button type="submit">do it</button>
  </form>
);

const ChildComponent = props => (
  <div>
    <h3>{props.data.city}</h3>
    <h4>{props.data.main.temp_min}</h4>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since data is fetched, it is not available right away (on render). Check if data is defined in the child component. Many ways to do it but this should suffice

```
const ChildComponent = props => (
  <div>
    {props.data && (
      <div>
        <h3>{props.data.city}</h3>
        <h4>{props.data.main.temp_min}</h4>
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Correct answer.....  or you can use a ternary operator to return this if defined and that if it's not... example ---

const ChildComponent = props => (
  <div>
    {props.data !== undefined ? (
      <div>
        <h3>{props.data.city}</h3>
        <h4>{props.data.main.temp_min}</h4>
      </div>
    ) : (<p>No data to display.</p>)}
  </div>
);